# Size limit for Cache Manifest with Phonegap on Android

Tags: android, cordova, size, cache-manifest

I'm currently developing a **single page web application**.
I'll post it on the AppStore and Play Store with **PhoneGap**.
To run my app offline, I use the **HTML5 Cache Manifest** : its final size is around 10MB.

When I test my app on google chrome, everything loads normally. :)
After that, I created an APK with PhoneGap to test the application on my Nexus 4.
Unfortunately I realized that the cache size is limited to 5MB.
I reduced the weight of the cache to 5MB, the cache loads correctly ! :)

I update the cache, I run the application and I get an error...
After some tests, if the cache size is less than 2.5MB loading and updating the cache works.

**I'd like to know if it's possible to increase the size limit of Cache Manifest with PhoneGap?**

Thanks in advance,

Matthieu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. You have to extend you **app.java** with the following lines.

```
//version 7+
//method available since API level 7 
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 7) {
    //set custom cache size (20 MB), as the default seems to be to small (5 MB)
    //this is deprecated from SDK 18 but seems still to be needed
    super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*20);
}
```

We had some **Error 10 on SQL transaction updates** and this patch fixed it by setting the limit to 20 MB.

Comment: Any ideas if some Cordova plugin already includes this functionality? Limiting the cache size is essential to avoid eating up all the internal memory.